# MediaPlayer onError is never called

Tags: java, interface, android-mediaplayer

MediaPlayer onError is never called, I tried to set even after `start ()` but the difference does not change, perhaps the problem is in asynchronous calls ... but is there a solution without disabling `prepareAsync ()`?

```
public void play() {
    try {
        if(player != null){
            player.stop();
            player.release();
            player = null;
        }

        player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setLooping(false);
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                player.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {}
        });

        playerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        player.setDataSource(urls[current]);
        player.prepareAsync();
        player.setOnErrorListener((mediaPlayer, error, i1) -> {
            Log.e("ErrorListener", "error=" + error);
            return false;
        });
        player.setOnPreparedListener(mediaPlayer -> {
            player.start();
            playerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        });

    } catch (Exception ex){
        menu.progressDialog.dismiss();
        Log.e("ErrorException", "" + ex.toString());
    }
}
```

`Void play ()` is in this class. Where "VideoPlayer" is the "interface":

```
public class myMediaPlayer implements VideoPlayer {
}
```

The error is definitely there. but the call does not occur except "OnPrepared" is not called.

Comment: Log `setOnPreparedListener` to see if it gets called. Also, provide more info, does it crash etc.

Comment: setOnPreparedListener () is also not called. And there is an error:  E/PlaylistFetcher: failed to load playlist at url 'http://<suppressed>'

But I can't catch her.

Comment: What is `urls[current]`? Where do you get your data from?

Comment: This is a String [] list. Here is an example link: http://persik.by/stream/2853/374241/10228.m3u8